# Pattern and Matcher is so strange in Android

Tags: android, regex

This Code is not working:

```
String description = Pattern.compile("<div.*?>(.*?)</div>", Pattern.DOTALL).matcher(html).group(1);
```

This Code is working:

```
Pattern pdescription = Pattern.compile("<div.*?>(.*?)</div>", Pattern.DOTALL);
Matcher mdescription = pdescription.matcher(html);
if (mdescription.find()) {
     String description = mdescription.group(1);
}
```

Why I need declare two objects?
Logcat wrote:

```
01-09 21:33:06.741: E/AndroidRuntime(1734): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-150    
01-09 21:33:06.741: E/AndroidRuntime(1734): java.lang.IllegalStateException: No successful match so far    
01-09 21:33:06.741: E/AndroidRuntime(1734):     at java.util.regex.Matcher.ensureMatch(Matcher.java:607)    
01-09 21:33:06.741: E/AndroidRuntime(1734):     at java.util.regex.Matcher.group(Matcher.java:358)    
01-09 21:33:06.741: E/AndroidRuntime(1734):     at com.ibelieve.news.SearchEngine.Baidu.GetNews(Baidu.java:45)    
01-09 21:33:06.741: E/AndroidRuntime(1734):     at com.ibelieve.news.MainActivity$2$1.run(MainActivity.java:52)    
01-09 21:33:06.741: E/AndroidRuntime(1734):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first example you haven't tried to find anything yet.

[As stated in the docs for `group`:](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#group%28%29)

> `IllegalStateException` - If no match has yet been attempted, or if the previous match operation failed